# Как оптимизировать работающий с индексами pooling/unpooling на theano?

Tags: cuda

Собственно, задача - максимально точно скопировать поведение слоёв [SpatialMaxPooling](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialMaxPooling%20SpatialMaxPooling) и [SpatialMaxUnpooling](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialMaxUnpooling) на theano.

При этом SpatialMaxUnpooling заполняет только те "ячейки" которые соотвествуют индексам максимальных значений в соответствующем SpatialMaxPooling.

Например - вот входное изображение

[image: Изображение до pooling]

SpatialMaxPooling же сохранит из каждого участка 2x2 пиксель с максимальных значением и его индекс.

И SpatialMaxUnpooling - задаст значение только тем пикселям, которые соответсвуют индексам. То есть на выходе будет

[image: изображение после unpooling]

Накидал такую реализацию :

```
def pooling2d_2x2(self, x):
    reshaped = x.reshape([
        x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] // 2, 2, x.shape[3] // 2, 2
    ])
    max_values, max_indices = T.max_and_argmax(reshaped, (3,5,))
    return max_values, max_indices

def unpooling2d_2x2(self, pooled, indices):
    tmp_shape = [pooled.shape[0], pooled.shape[1], pooled.shape[2], 2, pooled.shape[3], 2]
    # Resize image
    resized = pooled.repeat(2, 2).repeat(2, 3)
    pooled_reshaped = resized.reshape(tmp_shape)
    # Resize indices
    indices_repeaten = indices.repeat(2, 2).repeat(2, 3).reshape(tmp_shape)
    # Calculate output
    result = pooled_reshaped * 0.0
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 0, :, 0],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 0, :, 0] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 0, :, 0], 0))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 0, :, 1],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 0, :, 1] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 0, :, 1], 1))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 1, :, 0],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 1, :, 0] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 1, :, 0], 2))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 1, :, 1],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 1, :, 1] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 1, :, 1], 3))
    result_shape = [pooled.shape[0], pooled.shape[1], pooled.shape[2] * 2, pooled.shape[3] * 2]
    return result.reshape(result_shape)
```

Но быстротой она не отличилась (кстати, не отказался бы от рекомендаций - чем профилировать). Отсюда вопрос - что тут можно улучшить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующая замена (насколько я понимаю theano (а это, наверное, весьма посредственное понимание :-) ) - здесь мы уже не выделяем память под новый тензор и обращаемся только к "увеличенному" входному тензору и индексам) несколько увеличила скорость. Впрочем, возможно - есть и другие возможные улучшения?

```
def unpooling2d_2x2(self, pooled, indices):
    tmp_shape = [pooled.shape[0], pooled.shape[1], pooled.shape[2], 2, pooled.shape[3], 2]
    # Resize image
    resized = pooled.repeat(2, 2).repeat(2, 3)
    pooled_reshaped = resized.reshape(tmp_shape)
    # Resize indices
    indices_repeaten = indices.repeat(2, 2).repeat(2, 3).reshape(tmp_shape)
    # Calculate output
    result = pooled_reshaped * 0.0
    # Calculate output
    result = T.set_subtensor(pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 0, :, 0],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 0, :, 0] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 0, :, 0], 0))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 0, :, 1],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 0, :, 1] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 0, :, 1], 1))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 1, :, 0],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 1, :, 0] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 1, :, 0], 2))
    result = T.set_subtensor(result[:, :, :, 1, :, 1],
                             pooled_reshaped[:, :, :, 1, :, 1] * T.eq(indices_repeaten[:, :, :, 1, :, 1], 3))
    result_shape = [pooled.shape[0], pooled.shape[1], pooled.shape[2] * 2, pooled.shape[3] * 2]
```